# How to acces MariaDB with NodeJS on Windows

Tags: mysql, node.js, windows, mariadb

I just downloaded **MariaDB 10.3** for Windows ,created a database and trying to connect from a **NodeJS** server using `mysql` library.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost", 
  user: "root",
  password: "MariaDBPass",
  database:'DB_NAME',
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Result: " + result);
  });
});
```

I tried it on **Ubuntu** and it's working but on **windows** it throws an non-sql error:

```
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
```

I've red that maybe it is an incompatibility between MySQL 8.0 and the library(`mysql`).
I've already tried to alter the user as following :

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

but it said that

> there is an SQL Syntax Error

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Downgraded to what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how helpful this will be, but using the following setup:

- MariaDB 10.3 (x64)
- Windows 10 Pro (build 17763)
- mysql module v2.16.0.
- Node.js v10.15.1

The following code works as expected for me:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost", 
    user: "some_user",
    password: "some_password",
    database: 'testdb'
});

let sql = "select * from test_table";

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

I get an output like:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Mike Smith"},{"id":2,"name":"Joe Brown"}]
```

To create the user I did (using MariaDB mysql.exe, using root user):

```
use testdb;

create user 'some_user'@'localhost' identified by 'some_password';

grant all privileges on testdb.* to 'some_user'@'localhost';
```

This is maybe a little permissive, but it's ok for testing connections.

I can also connect with the root user.

If you wish to set the root user password, try:

```
use mysql;

update user set password=PASSWORD('password') where user='root'and host='localhost';

flush privileges;
```

I created a simple db 'testdb' and table 'test_table' with a couple of rows to use for queries.

I'd suggest perhaps upgrading your mysql module version if you can. Also maybe look at the Node.js version.

Comment: I made the same setup as yours and still the same error. Did you made some changes on the user? Did you used the root user as well?

Comment: I granted the user access to the database in question. That's pretty much it!

Comment: I would apreciate it verry mutch ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Strange enough , i changed the port from the default to Another value and now it’s working fine.

Comment: I think there ‘s a problem with the ubuntu terminal for Linux because i tried to download mariadb from the repos using apt